# How to updateAll using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to do an updateAll as follows:

```
// initialize the array
$array = array(
    "Land Rover" => array("LAND ROVER")
);

// loop both arrays
foreach($array as $new => $aOld) {
    foreach($aOld as $old) {
        $this->updateAll(array('make = $new'), array('make = $old'));
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rover  WHERE `make` = 'LAND ROVER'' at line 1
```

what I am after is:

```
UPDATE items SET make = 'Land Rover' WHERE make = 'LAND ROVER';
```

Please do not give me answers about case conversion as I have other array elements that are more than that.

How do I avoid the error? Actually, how do I dump the full sql? I am running this code in the `Console`.

Many thanks.

EDIT: I just got a debug for the SQL:

```
UPDATE `items` AS `Item`  SET `Item`.`id` = make =  "Land Rover"  WHERE `make` = '\"LAND ROVER\"'
```

An obvious problem but how did it get there?

Comment: refer this would be defiantly help you http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: @liyakat I already have. I have got the error by adapting the example shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values and conditions should be passed as an associative array;

```
$this->updateAll(
    array(
        'Item.make' => Sanitize::escape($new)
    ),
    array(
        'Item.make' => $old
    )
);
```

Note;
I'm not behind my computer and not sure if `Sanitize::escape()` already *quotes* the value, otherwise;

```
array(
    'Item.make' => "'" . Sanitize::escape($new) . "'"
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the values in `$fields` param yourself like the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_updateAll) says:

```
$this->updateAll(array("make = \"$new\""), array('make = $old'));
```

A more readable version would be:

```
$this->updateAll(array('make' => "\"$new\""), array('make' => $old));
```

Comment: the first one produced no error but didn't do anything. The second one put '$new' in the make field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->modelname->updateAll(array('make'=>"'$new'"), array('modelname.make'=>$old))

i hope its working
```